# Quantum wave function collapse by unknown observer

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, observers, wavefunction-collapse

If there's an "unknown" third-party observer of a particle, that would collapse the wave function for the first party, but has that "ever" happened, without knowing who the observer was. If so, what are the theories about who or what was the unknown observer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the observer or the camera collapse the wave function in the double slit experiment?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59974/does-the-observer-or-the-camera-collapse-the-wave-function-in-the-double-slit-ex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wave function doesn't collapse. The reason why you don't see interference in everyday life is that interference is suppressed when information is copied out of a system and that happens very quickly for objects we can see

https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3245

https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2832

Information being copied out of a system may happen as a result of a measurement but will more often happen as a result of being immersed in an environment, e.g. - your body heats the gas in the room you're sitting in and changes how it flows around the room, and light reflects off your body regardless of whether you or anyone else observes it.

Since you don't experience interference there are multiple versions of you, each of which sees only one version of the systems around you

https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2832

https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328

The notion of wave function collapse produces many problems with causality and is difficult to reconcile with experiment:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568

https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4746