Observation in Young's double slit experiment
I'm new to YDSE and recently I found out that there was also an experiment done when humans were able to separate photons (What I mean is we were able to shoot photons onto the double slit) so it was observed that it showed same pattern as light does, but weirdness started when we kept a detector at slit entrance and tried to know exactly from which slit did the photon passed through but when we did so the wave interference wasn't shown instead it was like shooting particles onto a screen.
Scientists came to a conclusion (well I don't know if they did or not but I just heard it on YouTube channels) that when there is an observer, photons behave like particles. When there is no detector, it showed a wave interference. But since we are looking at it, aren't we also an observer? We do have consciousness. So why don't we, as an observer, cause the photons to behave like particles here?
I may be wrong about this whole concept so I welcome any correction and happy to know what actually is YDSE if I'm wrong.

This is just one man's opinion, but here goes.  It is apparent that ANY experiment that can determine which slit the photon goes through produces a particle result, regardless of how that experiment is designed, including the quantum eraser experiment.  This implies that there is some sort of conservation of information law that hasn't yet been mathematically formalized.  To wit, if you know which slit the photon goes through, you get a particle result, and if you don't know which slit the photon goes through, you get a wave result, ALWAYS.

@DavidWhite, I would have said, "...you get the same result that you would have got if the other slit were closed." That's not the same as a "particle result." A single slit diffracts photons and, it projects an interference pattern (distinct from the two-slit pattern) because the it's really the two distinct edges of the slit that cause the diffraction. All of that is wave-like behavior.

This answer should resolve the confusion: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/499690/186017

@my2cts Both of the top 2 answers at your link (which is also referenced in the Close notification) are technically wrong. The top answer states "What the camera will basically do is cause an abrupt change in the state of the particle." That might be true in some setups, but not all. See my answer below and related reference. Place polarizers across the 2 slits. If oriented one way, there is interference. Shift them another way, NO interference. The which-slit information itself is never known or otherwise observed, intensity remains the same. So it isn't the "camera", because there isn't one.

@DrChinese I agree.

You can dim a laser beam until you find that light is only detected in chunks if you have a very sensitive detector. Those chunks are called photons.
You can arrange a double or single slit experiment with a very dim laser beam so that there is a very high probability that there is less than one photon at a time going through the experiment. When a photon goes through one slit you will see a particular pattern of light and dark stripes. If you open up a second slit you will see a different pattern of light and dark stripes: this is called quantum interference. Some places that were formerly lit will be dark and vice versa. If you consider a place that was lit with one slit and dark with two slits then something must be coming through the second slit to stop a photon from arriving there. That thing is blocked by opaque materials, deflected by lenses and mirrors as a photon would be. You will only ever see a photon pass through one slit if you measure it but the other invisible photon has to be there or you can't explain the results of experiments. If you put detectors in front of just one slit you will see a single slit pattern so the invisible photon is interacting with something that blocks photons as a detector would but the detector you see doesn't go off so there must be an invisible detector too. Quantum theory claims that each object exists in multiple versions that are approximately sorted into layers each of which looks like the universe as described by classical physics. This is often called the many worlds interpretation of quantum theory, but it is the only known explanation of single photon interference and many other experiments and it is a consequence of the equations of motion of quantum theory unless they are modified. See "The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch Chapter 2 for a popular explanation.
A measurement or observation is just an interaction with a system that copies information out of that system. This kind of interaction tends to suppress quantum interference through an effect called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
If you're just looking at an experiment while photons are going through it that doesn't change anything because you're not actually interacting with the photons so you're not causing decoherence and the interference remains intact.

Thanks this really helped me to understand what actually happnes and your explanation to there being a invisible photon (like as of this photon is created out of fabric of space and quickly disappear after the interaction I guess??)is really quiet fascinating and does explain what's going on but as far as I know isn't a photon not actually like a gaussian wave packet (which many people use for interpretation of what quanta(photon is )) ,but isn't photon like infinitely long ? So why can it make sense for a photon being so long to interact with it self when we pass it through double slit?

And yeah so I got it clear that for quantum mechanics to show its weirdness we need to try and measure it and this act to try to measure it results in decoherence and hence being just a observer we don't interact with it hence a consciousness don't affect quantum weirdness.

When you're doing a double slit experiment you usually don't do it with a Gaussian wave packet: a plane wave will often be a good approximation. But detectors decohere a set of states that are highly peaked in position and momentum and thinking of those states as being like Gaussian wavepackets isn't too misleading.
You don't decohere an interfering photon unless you interact with it. Actually observing a photon undergoing inteference, e.g. - by sticking your eye in front of a slit, will cause it to decohere.

So we can use that interpretation ,but isnt photon actually a infinitly long EM wave and why cant it interfere with it self ?? As it is way too long and why are you going with the theory of there being an invisible photon, well it does explain but why can it just interfer with it self instade of another invisible photon?? Wait why does actually watching the interference closer results in decoherence? Like we didn't interact with photon like what a detector does (EMCCD) so why is it affecting decoherence??

@Neel good questions, lots of answers out there by academics ... they get paid to write papers, beware.  The best and simplest IMO is that an excited electron/atom in the source is already interacting with the EM field ... long before the actual photon emission.  Thus the EM field (which perceives all the electrons in the apparatus) guides all energy direction i.e.the photons.  It is the EM field that sees the 2 slits... it is the dumb photon/enery that just goes where it is told .... thus the photon is guided ... or as Dirac liked to say "interferes with itself".

@Neel  So science never tried to observe which slit for photons, the expt was done with electrons.  If you observe a photon ... poof it is gone.  An electron when observed/interacted with by a photon after the slit will lose the effect of the 2 slits (EM field) and simply crash to the screen with no pattern.

@Neel When you measure the light you see a photon. And you only ever see it in one position, e.g. - if you measure light at the slits you only ever see it at one slit. But interference patterns and changes in them are not consistent with a photon going through just one slit. So there is something going through both slits and the things going through each slit act like photons except that you only ever see one of them. So there are things involved in the experiment that act like photons except that you don't see them.

Each version of the photon picks up a phase as it moves through space or materials or whatever and the plane wave describes the phase relationships between the different versions of the photon. But you can't just say the light is acting like a wave because it is detected in discrete chunks.

@PhysicsDave um I kinda get the idea of photons being directed in a specific path but still can't understand what your trying to say, currently I just 2nd year high school student so it's kinda hard for me to understand it now could you suggest books which you learned from ?? Or shall I go with Feynman lectures ?

@alanf I can't understand your reason for there being invisible photons but I'll be glad if you could suggest me some books ,to be honest I'm just 2nd yr high school student and totally new to this weirdness , I you followed any book please recommend me it might let me understand your way of reason

"The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch, "QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter " by Feynman are probably suitable. The Feynman lectures are good and they're available here https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/

@Neel. On this site you can search my name, I answer a lot on photon path.  You need to know that the EM field is everywhere!

@alanf thanks this was helpfull

@PhysicsDave yep well many times I did read your explanation on many ques. Thanks for trying to explain me it was wonderful

No humans required! The apparatus setup can be varied to yield either an interference pattern or not without ever learning which slit the photons go through. It is enough that it is possible to learn that information.
See this experiment (which unfortunately is fairly advanced) which explains and demonstrates this.
Young’s Double Slit Experiment with Single Photons and Quantum Eraser
https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/files/science-demonstrations/files/single_photon_paper.pdf

I have yet to see a real photo of the two lines where the photons act like "little baseballs"

@Lambda Photons do not make that kind of pattern, because there is single slit diffraction from each of the 2 slits even when there is no interference. See my answer's reference, Figure 9. This shows what you see when there is no interference pattern, while Figure 8 shows the comparable image with interference.

Photons always have both particle and wave properties just like we have arms and legs.  When we are observed walking we see the leg properties, when we are waving we see the arm properties.  For the photon the slits can show the wave properties.
Even mass particles like electrons and small molecules will show wave properties thru slits ... that is because like the photons the interaction between the a screen/detector and the particle is governed/ruled by the EM field.
If you want to understand light you can always say that light is a very small (local in science) and individual wave in the EM field.  All photons are ruled by the EM field.

Yeah I kinda get your idea regarding lights dual nature but this wasn't the question tho.

Let me put it like this: According to the postulate of quantum mechanics, "The act of making an observation inherently disturbs the quantum system being observed".
Imagine you are observing the motion of a moving car. How do you even see the car? It is because the light particles (which have momentum) are hitting the car, gets reflected and come straight to your eyes. Will the motion of the car change if you don't observe it? NO, because the photons have very small momentum to change the motion of that car.
But imagine if the car gets replaced by an electron. Now, if you try to observe it, you have to do something. This act of observation disturbs the system and the photons now have enough momentum to change the motion of an electron. Hence the system gets disturbs and yields different result.
In the double-slit experiment, the system gets disturb when we observe it and changes the result.

"Disturbance" is not necessary to eliminate interference. Yes, that occurs in most double slit experiments, but not in all. See this reference (or look at my answer), in which the exact same "disturbance" occurs regardless of whether interference is produced or not. Fig. 8 has polarizers aligned parallel, and there IS interference. Fig. 9 has the polarizers aligned perpendicular, and there is NO interference. Either way, there is a polarizer over each slit - only the orientation is varied.  https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/files/science-demonstrations/files/single_photon_paper.pdf

What you call a postulate sounds like the Observer Effect. I've never seen this in a list of postulates, but I can understand the confusion. It sounds a lot like the Projection Postulate.

@DrChinese thanks for the correction.
